# change of all immediate elements of the corrosponding class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my html content

```
 <li class="info"> info<li>
 <li class="other"> info<li>
 <li class="other"> info<li>

 <li class="Error"> error<li>
 <li class="other"> error<li>
 <li class="warning"> warning<li>
 <li class="other"> warning<li>
 <li class="other"> warning<li>
 <li class="info"> info<li>
 <li class="other"> info<li>
 <li class="other"> info<li>
```

based on the li element class, I want to filter only the immediate li.other class item css to be changed using jquery;

I followed the below approach: when I select info elements:

```
  $('.info').prevAll('li.other').css({});
```

It worked but it will all the previous li.other elements changed. Instead I want only specific to that particular html(info) element li.other element. rest all to be ignored.
 Please any one provide the possible approach

Comment: $(this).next().find('.other').css({});

Comment: Try this link: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`prevUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/prevUntil) method with [`:not()` pseudo-class selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector) to achieve the result.

```
$('.info').prevUntil(':not(li.other)').css({});
```

```js
$('.info').prevUntil(':not(li.other)').css({
  color: 'red'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="info"> info</li>
  <li class="other"> info</li>
  <li class="other"> info</li>
  <li class="Error"> error</li>
  <li class="other"> error</li>
  <li class="warning"> warning</li>
  <li class="other"> warning</li>
  <li class="other"> warning</li>
  <li class="info"> info</li>
  <li class="other"> info</li>
  <li class="other"> info</li>
</ul>
```

---

In case you need the three `warning` then you need to get the last element and add it to the selector using [`addBack()`](https://api.jquery.com/addBack/) method.

```
$('.info').prevUntil(':not(li.other)').prev().addBack().css({});
```

```js
$('.info').prevUntil(':not(li.other)').prev().addBack().css({
  color: 'red'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="info"> info</li>
  <li class="other"> info</li>
  <li class="other"> info</li>
  <li class="Error"> error</li>
  <li class="other"> error</li>
  <li class="warning"> warning</li>
  <li class="other"> warning</li>
  <li class="other"> warning</li>
  <li class="info"> info</li>
  <li class="other"> info</li>
  <li class="other"> info</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It only displays one html element, I want to display all elements, in between

Comment: @prudviraju :  what you mean

Comment: as per your code selects highlights only the immediate first element. I want to show all the immediate , in your case three warning to be highlighted

Comment: @prudviraju :  glad to help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160695/discussion-between-pranav-c-balan-and-prudvi-raju).

Answer (score 0):

You can use next to solve this query

```
 $('.other').next().css({});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $("info + other").css({});
```